# add menu items into jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a filter I added to a datatable (jquery datatable) which worked perfectly until I figured out how to add it to the header.

I originally handled is like so:

```
$('select#booking_status').change( function() { oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val() ); } );
```

Which worked until I added the select menu inside the header with the sDom feature

```
"sDom": '<"H"<"tools">lfr>t<"F"ip>'
```

[image: My Filter]

I'm also not sure on the last part, but I couldn't seem to get it to work where it was until i followed the example and wrapped the select like so...

```
$("div.tools").html('Organize by: <select id="booking_status"><option value="">All Bookings</option><option value="confirmed">Upcoming</option><option value="arrived">Arrived</option><option value="rejected">Rejected</option></select>');
```

It was initially just in the div outside the table.

http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html

Comment: one other thing is, when it did work, it was inserting the option from the select directly into the search box.  It's filtering based on a hidden column, so I'd like it not to show up in the search box at all.

Comment: when I put the tools div in the HTML directly, it hides it, and the space where it should be in the header is taken, but is blank as is the div.